# How to find pink highlighted json errors in sublime text

Tags: json, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I'm working with a large json file.

This json has been parsed by myself using Python, and (as a result) there are some json validation errors at different points in the file. I want to identify these errors in order to improve my Python parser.

Sublime text (2) helpfully highlights in pink formatting errors in the json, however working my way through 70,000,000 lines of json to find these errors is somewhat challenging.

Is there any way to skip to pink highlighted errors in the json?

(Note: the json file is sufficiently large that trying to use an online validator for example is not possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in a fancy way using a plugin, but for your purposes probably the best way is to just enter a command into the [console](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#sublime-text-is-programmable). Open your JSON file with errors in it, then open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>. Paste in the following code and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
view.show_at_center(view.find_by_selector("invalid.illegal")[0])
```

and the view will scroll to show the first error in the file. Fix that error, click back on the console entry line, hit the up arrow to bring back the command you just ran, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and it should scroll to the next error, and so on. When there are no more errors, you'll get `IndexError: list index out of range` printed to the console, and the view won't scroll any more.

---

While this will work in both Sublime Text 2 and 3, I **strongly** urge you to upgrade to [ST3](https://sublimetext.com/3) if at all possible. ST2 has been shelved and deprecated, and there will be no more bug fixes released. Development is now focused solely on ST3 (as well as being in the planning stages for ST4!). [*`"I don't know of any good reason to not use Sublime Text 3"`*](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4) - Will Bond, ST core developer.

There are a *ton* of new features and bug fixes in the new version, even if you're just using the [public beta](https://sublimetext.com/3). (BTW, don't let the word "beta" fool you - the program is rock solid, and has been for years.) If you want more cutting-edge features, and are a [registered user](https://www.sublimetext.com/buy) (which you should be if you are using the program long-term or for commercial purposes), you can download the [dev builds](https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) which are updated more frequently, but run the *slight* chance of having an undetected bug or two.

One of the major advantages of ST3 is that it now supports a new, YAML-based [`sublime-syntax`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) highlighting engine, which allows for much greater flexibility than the old [`.tmLanguage`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) highlighting files (which are still supported). Related to that, the syntax files have all been [open-sourced](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) and development is proceeding very rapidly on them, even though it's been a few months since the last build was released.

Probably the biggest reason to upgrade is the plugin community. The internal [Python API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) has been updated to Python 3 (3.3.6, to be precise), which had the side effect of making many old plugins incompatible. Except in a few rare cases, most plugins now support ST3, and many are dropping ST2 support by the wayside as it becomes too difficult to maintain two codebases, as well as trying to develop with the much more limited API ST2 provides. So, unless you absolutely depend on an old ST2-only plugin that can't be ported, upgrading is definitely the best path to take.

Comment: perfect, thanks! Regarding ST3 you're right actually, I've just stuck to 2 as I've not felt the need to upgrade but I'm sure if I start using 3 I'll find reasons to stick to it.